# what is the best practice to align a text right next to a html div element

Tags: html, css

I was creating a unordered list and in that list I wanted to add a color pallete type window and I tried to create one the following way

```
<ul><li><div style="width:10px; height:10px;  background-color:#0066cc; float:left;"></div>test</li></ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wNkmJ/

I am attaching a fiddle link to see the output.. Is there a good way to align the div to text or should I just adjust the margin of div element, but I dont think that is the best possible solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your div, set:

```
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
float: none;
```

This positions the div in much the same way that images are positioned.

Comment: Note also you don't have to explicitly set `float: none`; that's the default so you can just not set `float` at all.

Comment: I don't want to duplicate question since I have almost similar problem. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NzG5V/4/ I just can not find any difference or mistake. Could you have a look at it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, having `line-height` for `li` will be a good choice.

From your JSfiddle,

```
li{
    line-height: 10px;   
}
```

check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/wNkmJ/1/).